# Paypal Email Verification using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

- I am using paypal-adaptive gem in myapp and i have multiple receivers
  there, one is admin and second one is project owner.Now I want to
  verify each project owner email using paypal and need following steps
  :
- In Project owner account settings there is a form containing  input
  PayPal Email & name of project owner
- When click one submit ,it should redirect to paypal and project 
  owner should login  in Paypal to verify application & redirect to my 
  app & get verified .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate Paypal with Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411337/how-to-integrate-paypal-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I'm working on the same topic. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you are still looking:

> The GetVerifiedStatus API operation lets you determine whether the
>   specified PayPal account's status is verified or unverified.
>
> A PayPal account achieves verified status under a variety of
>   circumstances, such as when an account is linked to a verified funding
>   source. Verified status indicates a trust relationship. For more
>   information about verified status, see the Frequently asked questions
>   about the verification process.

**Note:** In addition to GetVerifiedStatus, you can use Log In with PayPal or the Permissions API to gather information about PayPal users. Please see the documentation of these interfaces for more information.

Read more on document: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/